# Zurb Foundation For Emails gulp --production Fails

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-ink

I've been using Zurb Foundation for Emails successfully for quite some time. Suddenly the build process is failing.

I updated to Node 7.7.2 and NPM 4.1.2, deleted the node_modules directory and ran `npm install` to reinstall the dependencies, but it didn't solve the issue.

```
$ npm run build

foundation-emails-template@1.0.0 build /Users/[REDACTED]
gulp --production

[12:46:56] Requiring external module babel-register
[12:46:57] Using gulpfile ~/[REDACTED]/gulpfile.babel.js
[12:46:57] Starting 'default'...
[12:46:57] Starting 'build'...
[12:46:57] Starting 'clean'...
[12:46:57] Finished 'clean' after 11 ms
[12:46:57] Starting 'pages'...
[12:46:59] Finished 'pages' after 1.32 s
[12:46:59] Starting 'sass'...
[12:47:05] 'sass' errored after 6.91 s
[12:47:05] Error in plugin 'gulp-uncss'
Message:
    Unexpected EOF
Details:
    domainEmitter: [object Object]
    domain: [object Object]
    domainThrown: false
[12:47:05] 'build' errored after 8.25 s
[12:47:05] 'default' errored after 8.25 s

npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "build"
npm ERR! node v7.7.2
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! foundation-emails-template@1.0.0 build: `gulp --production`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the foundation-emails-template@1.0.0 build script 'gulp --production'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the foundation-emails-template package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
```

Or if I try to run `gulp --production` by itself:

```
$ gulp --production
[12:29:38] Requiring external module babel-core/register
[12:29:39] Using gulpfile ~/[REDACTED]/gulpfile.babel.js
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:129
    gulpInst.start.apply(gulpInst, toRun);
                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:129:19
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
```

`npm start` works as expected; I just can't inline the styles.

Any ideas? TIA.

Answer (score 6):

It's because the node environment had changed.

Run this in your console:

```
npm rebuild node-sass
npm rebuild gulp-uncss
```

It should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and was caused by a code-specific issue so make sure all your code is valid. In my case I was missing a closing `"` on a class.